# How to connect socket.io to a non-website application?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, discord.js

I made a discord bot (with discord.js) and i want to connect it with socket.io to send and receive a message from a website.

For website I use express.

How to connect socket.io to a non-website application?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the websocket protocol to send and receive messages from a web page, you should use the built in WebSocket class. Your code can look something like this:

```js
const socekt = new WebSocket("ws://[INSERT YOUR SERVER ADDRESS HERE]", ["wamp"]);
socket.onopen = () => {
  //code to be executed, when the websocket connection was opened
  console.log("Connection made!");
}
socket.onmessage = event => {
  //code to be executed, when a message is recieved. 
  console.log(event.data);
}
socket.onclose = event => {
  //code to be executed, when the connection is closed
  console.log(`Connection closed with code ${event.code}.`);
}
//function to send a message via the websocket
function sendMessage(message) {
  socket.send(message);
}
```